# Sending json to (not REST) WCF service

Tags: javascript, .net, json, wcf

I need to have a javascript which will send object as json to WCF service to save it.
I have javascript:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

                    $("#submitButton").click(function() {

console.info("executing submitButton click");
TestJSon();
 );
      });
       </script>
        <button type="button" id="submitButton">Save</button>
        <script>
            var varType;
            var varUrl;
            var varData;
            var varContentType;
            var varDataType;
            var varProcessData;          
            //Generic function to call AXMX/WCF  Service        
            function CallService() 
            {
            console.log('called CallService')
                    $.ajax({
                        type        : varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                        url         : varUrl, // Location of the service
                        data        : varData, //Data sent to server
                        contentType : varContentType, // content type sent to server
                        dataType    : varDataType, //Expected data format from server
                        processdata : varProcessData, //True or False
                        success     : function(msg) {//On Successfull service call
                        ServiceSucceeded(msg);                    
                        },
                        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                    });
        }

        function ServiceSucceeded(result) {//When service call is sucessful
       alert('Service call succeded');
             varType=null;varUrl = null;varData = null;varContentType = null;varDataType = null;varProcessData = null;     
        }
        function ServiceFailed(result) {
            alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            varType = null; varUrl = null; varData = null; varContentType = null; varDataType = null; varProcessData = null;     
        }



        function TestJSon() {
                varType = "POST";
            varUrl = "http://localhost:56616/bebc179a-3a96-4934-88df-df1ca17da8b1/CountryDataService.svc/SaveObject";
            varData = { player: {'Name': '1' }};
            varContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            varDataType = "json";
            varProcessData = true;
            CallService();

        }
</script>
```

This script should use this method of WCF:

```
 public void SaveObject(Player player)
        {
             var input = player;
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\Temp\" + "index.html", input.Name, Encoding.UTF8);
            return player;
        }
```

on service interface it is:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        void SaveObject(Player player);
```

Player class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Player")]
    public class Player
    {
        private string _name;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }     

    }
```

in the config I have:

```
<services>
 <service name="MyCompany.Services.CountryDataService" behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyCompany.Services.ICountryDataService" behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior"/>
  </service>
```

```
   <behaviors>     
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors> 
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>          
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>     
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

and the most important - the result:
Method ServiceFailed has been hit with code 0 and statusText - NoTransport
There was also no traffic (Fiddler told me)
the address of service is ok, because when I changed json to jsonp ServiceFailed also has been hit with code 200 and statusText - success.

And there was a traffic:

Request

```
GET http://localhost:56616/bebc179a-3a96-4934-88df-df1ca17da8b1/CountryDataService.svc/SaveObject?callback=jQuery1710486683341013641_1342788918981&player%5BName%5D=1&_=1342788921786 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:56616
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2012 12:55:21 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Endpoint not found.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, I need help with saving this Player object at my WCF service. I'm using Wk8 and .net 4.0

I will be gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do this step by step so that you could have a starting base.

1. Create a new Empty ASP.NET application
2. Add a model class

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class Player
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. A service contract:

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface ICountryDataService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
       void SaveObject(Player player);
   }
   ```
4. And an implementation:

   ```
   public class CountryDataService : ICountryDataService
   {
       public void SaveObject(Player player)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add an .svc endpoint (`CountryDataService.svc`):

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost 
       Language="C#" 
       Debug="true" 
       Service="MyService.CountryDataService" 
   %>
   ```
6. Modify web.config:

   ```
   <system.serviceModel>
       <behaviors>
         <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
             <webHttp/>
           </behavior>
         </endpointBehaviors>          
           <serviceBehaviors>
               <behavior name="">
                   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
               </behavior>
           </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <services>
           <service name="MyService.CountryDataService">
             <endpoint 
               address="" 
               binding="webHttpBinding" 
               contract="MyService.ICountryDataService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="CountryProvinceBehavior" />
           </service>          
       </services>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
   ```
7. Add an `index.htm` to consume:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $.ajax({
               url: 'countrydataservice.svc/saveobject',
               type: 'POST',
               contentType: 'application/json',
               data: JSON.stringify({ player: { Name: 'foo bar'} }),
               success: function (result) {

               }
           });
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

---

UPDATE:

And here's a link to my sample solution: http://www.filedropper.com/myservice

Comment: thank you @Darin Dimitrov for your reply. I've created new solution but I got the same result - No transport. I've tried with  'http://localhost:63341/CountryDataService.svc' and nothing. Also I don't see any traffic in Fiddler.

Comment: Did you notice the url in my answer? It's relative: `countrydataservice.svc/saveobject`, not absolute. Also I have tested this with ASP.NET 4.0. Are you using the same version? I will update my answer to provide you a link to download my sample, working solution.

Comment: Thanks for upload. It works now. The problem was I set countrydataservice.svc as start page, not index.htm. And then address of site was [physical path]/index.htm and error: the system cannot locate the resource specified. But as start page is localhost:63341/index.htm and it works how it should. So now we know that we the service is correct. How can I know use it by website outside of the project location?

Comment: What do you mean *outside of the project location*? Are you aware that cross domain AJAX calls are forbidden? That's due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into the browsers. If the page hosting your javascript (index.htm) is not hosted on the exactly same domain as your WCF service you cannot call it from javascript using AJAX. So your index.htm page must reside in the same project as the WCF service.

Comment: That explains a lot. Customers will be in the same domain so there wouldn't be any problem (I hope). Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the wrong element in the endpoint behavior.
Try replacing `<webHttp/>` with `<enableWebSCript/>` in your config.

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CountryProvinceBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: Thank you @channs for your reply. I did how you said (plus changing BodyStyle to WrapedRequest) and the result with json is the same(no traffic, and status NoTransport). But with the jsonp now response is
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Method not allowed.</p>
. Do you know what could be wrong ?

Comment: @user278618 - You haven't shown your service implementation code, have you set the attribute `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` on it?

Comment: I had added this attribute and got the same result (with json and jsonp). My service implemenention is default (only [ServiceContract] attribute). Page is not asp.net but clean HTML with javascript. I will reward you by 100 points if you help me.

Comment: @user278618 - I noticed your url is '.../CountryDataService.svc/ReturnTheSameObject', shouldn't it be '.../CountryDataService.svc/SaveObject'? This may be a typo in the question or your code, please confirm.

Comment: @user278618 - Saw that the `WebInvoke` attribute is missing the `RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` property. Can you add this and try again? `WebMessageFormat` enum has `XML` as the first member and no default is specified for `WebInvoke.WebMessageFormat`, hence my suggestion. I assume you are doing rebuild + clear-browser-cache + iisreset each time.

Answer (score 1):

When you set endpoint behaviour configuration to use `<enableWebScript />` WCF generates for you JavaScript Proxy endpoint. So it will be more simple for you to use it out of box.

**Web.config file**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="Service.TestService">
    <endpoint address="" contract="Service.ITestService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Service contract**

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "TestService", Namespace = "Service")]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int GetSum(int a, int b);
}
```

For example, your service hosted on `localhost/TestService.svc`, then to get JavaScript proxy class code you should go to url `localhost/TestService.svc/js`

**How to use JS proxy class**

```
var proxy = new Service.TestService(); 
proxy.GetSum(1, 2, function(response) { alert('Result: ' + response); }, function(response) { alert('Error'); }, proxy);
```

For more info look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412167.aspx